# redirect all traffic for a certain domain using nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver, redirect, http-redirect

I'm currently playing around with nginx and am trying to redirect all traffic for e.g. firstdomain.org to seconddomain.org This is working fine with a simple redirect but I now also want it to hand on the URI, the scheme and the subdomain.

E.g.

`http(s)://firstdomain.org/` redirects to `http(s)://seconddomain.org/`,
`http(s)://firstdomain.org/test` redirects to `http(s)://seconddomain.org/test`,
`http(s)://test.firstdomain.org/` redirects to `http(s)://test.seconddomain.org/`
and so on..

My current set up is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<sub>\w+)\.firstdomain\.org$, firstdomain.org;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificatekety;

    location / {
        if ($sub = '') {
                return 301 $scheme://seconddomain.org$request_uri;
        }
        return 301 $scheme://$sub.seconddomain.org$request_uri;
    }
}
```

This is redirecting links without subdomain just fine but as soon as it's e.g. `http(s)://test.subdomain.org` or `http(s)://test.subdomain.org/test` it does not work anymore.

Is there anything I have missed or is there maybe even an easier way nginx supports to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify by capturing the `.` in `$sub`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<sub>\w+\.)?firstdomain\.org$;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificatekety;

    return 301 "$scheme://${sub}seconddomain.org$request_uri";
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much!
Just one note: It looks like you need to add `firstdomain.org` to the `server_name` as well, otherwise it won't redirect plain `http(s)://firstdomain.org` requests.

Comment: @Luca Oops sorry. I have added a `?` to the regex to make the capture optional.

Comment: I removed `firstdomain.org` again and added the `?`. Now everything is working as expected. Thank you!